Clone folder directory
I want to create a script to clone a folder from the directory "../x/A/" to "../y/A/" and remove files from the directory "../y/A/" that are not in ".. /x /A/".
I wrote the removal part. Is it possible to optimize this somehow? (I'm self-taught, so maybe I'm missing something)
I would also like to know if there are ready-made solutions for what I want?
from pathlib import Path
import os

directory_path1 = 'E:\**\path01'
directory_path2 = 'E:\**\path2_\path01'
base_fold = Path(directory_path1).name
local_delete_list = []
#absolute_delete_list = []


def get_files_paths(directory, mode = False):

    directory = Path(directory)
    if mode == True:
        files_paths = [file_path.parent.name +'/' +file_path.name for file_path in directory.rglob('*') if file_path.is_file()]
    else:
        files_paths = [file_path for file_path in directory.rglob('*') if file_path.is_file()]
    return files_paths


absolute_list_path1 = tuple([str(x) for x in tuple(get_files_paths(directory_path1))])
absolute_list_path2 = tuple([str(x) for x in tuple(get_files_paths(directory_path2))])

local_list_path1 = []
local_list_path2 = []


for i in absolute_list_path1:
    local_list_path1.append(i.replace(i[0:i.index(str(base_fold))],''))
for i in absolute_list_path2:
    local_list_path2.append(i.replace(i[0:i.index(str(base_fold))],''))


for path in local_list_path2:
    if path not in local_list_path1:
        local_delete_list.append(path)


for i in absolute_list_path2:
    for j in local_delete_list: 
        print(i, ' || ', j)
        try:
            if i.index(j):
                #print(i,' -match found- ' , j)
                os.remove(i)

        except:
            print("no matches")


P.S. In the comments they wrote about rsync, maybe this is what I need, but I use Windows, I’m not sure that this thing will help me

Ready-made solution: rsync -a --delete ../x/A/ ../y/A/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


I want to create a script to clone a folder from the directory "../x/A/" to "../y/A/" and remove files from the directory "../y/A/" that are not in "../x /A/".

Why not just delete directory ../y/A and then copy ../x/A to ../y/A? Sounds like you are somewhat accomplishing that by deleting everything in ../y/A not already present in ../x/A.
You can use shutil for the following:
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('../y/A/')
shutil.copytree('../x/A', '../y/A')


the fact is that I store 2 copies of my data on different disks and sometimes I change the names or transfer some files, so no new data appears, but during normal copying Windows cannot determine that a file already exists, it just lies in another catalogue,
Therefore, I want to write a script that will monitor the state of directory X and copy the missing files to directory Y from X
The first reason why I can't just delete Y is because it weighs a lot ~200gb and has a lot of files
The second is that I don’t want to once again load my main disk with copying the same

Quite unexpectedly, I found a built-in utility for cloning files and directories - robocopy.exe as a ready-made solution.
